# SQL Injection flaw

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

I am working on a project where the client has reported an SQL injection flaw in the code. Here is my code…

```
1 public int ExecuteNonQuery(string query, SqlParameter[] parameters)
2 {
3   using (SqlCommand command = CreateCommand(query, parameters))
4   {
5       int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
6       return rowsAffected;
7   }
8 }
```

And the `CreateCommand` method goes as

```
private SqlCommand CreateCommand(string commandText, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    SqlCommand retVal = this.connection.CreateCommand();
    retVal.CommandText = commandText;
    retVal.CommandTimeout = this.commandsTimeout;
    retVal.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    return retVal;
}
```

The flaw is reported at **line number 3**. I am unable to understand what kind of attack an happen here as this is a console application. But I have to fix the flaw and I don't know how to fix it.

Query is

```
@"delete from {0} where runId in 
( select runId from {0}
  inner join 
    ( select sId as sId_last,
        wfId as wfId_last,
        max(runId) as runId_last from {0} where endTime is NULL
        group by sId, wfId ) t1
  on endTime is NULL and sId = sId_last and wfId = wfId_last
  and (runId <> runId_last or startTime < @aDateTime)
)";
```

Help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what SQL Injection is?

Comment: Yes, I do understand. The question is it is not a web based application. it is a console application which is not having any text fields to enter data in it.

Comment: post your query..there may be loop hole

Comment: @utility: I have posted the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've exposed a `public` method which can be accessed by any code that allows any SQL expression to be executed.

I would look at changing that method to being `internal` or `private` instead so that not just any code can call that method.

Answer (score 5):

*that* code is injection-free... But note that the methods that call `ExecuteNonQuery` could build the `query` by composing strings.

An injection attack happens when you do something like:

```
string name = ...; // A name selected by the user.
string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name = '" + name + "'";
```

so when you compose a query using pieces of text that are of external origin.

Note that a more subtle injection attack could be multi-level:

```
string name = // The result of a query to the db that retrieves some data
              // sadly this data has been manipulated by the attacker

string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name = '" + name + "'";
```

In general you don't need a user interface to cause an injection attack...

You could query something from a web site/from the db, and use the unsanitized result to query the db (as in the last example), causing an injection attack... Or even using the content of the configuration file could cause an injection attack: the priviledges needed to modify the configuration file could be different than the ones needed to do something on the DB, and a malicious user could have the priviledges to modify the configuration file but not have direct access to the DB. So he could use the program as a trojan horse against the DB.

**about the query**

The weak point of that query (that is a composition of strings) is in how the `{0}` is calculated. Is it a string chosen in a group of fixed strings? Something like:

```
string tableName;

if (foo)
   tableName = "Foo";
else if (bar)
   tableName = "Bar";
```

or is it something more user controlled?

If the table names are fixed in code, then there shouldn't be any injection attack possible. If the table names are "extracted" from some user input/some other table the user could have access, we return to the problem I showed before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I validate the query. Do I need to validate the parameters also?

Comment: @NJMR `SqlParameter` are "secure". An Injection attack is only against the "textual" part of the query. Note that there is another family of attacks where the user for example finds how to query directly by `Id` and is able to query informations that he shouldn't be able to query... For example, let's say that your site has addresses like: `http://mysite.xxx/user/123` where `123` is the `id` of the user. An user could try writing `http://mysite.xxx/user/200` and see what happens... But as I've said, it is another family of attacks.

Comment: Worth mentioning that parametrized queries are not 100% secure, these are still vulnerable to injection attacks if the query does something stupid with the parameters. I've seen a stored proc that concatenated the parameter inside of a string query e.g. `SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name LIKE ''%' + @term+ '%'''`. Pretty dumb but it happens more often than you'd think.

Comment: @DGibbs Yep... I was forgetting that! If you use EXEC to execute something, you are looking for trouble :-)

Answer (score 2):

Line 3:

```
 using (SqlCommand command = CreateCommand(query, parameters))
```

Both Query and parameters are available in this line.

SQL injection should not be prevented by trying to validate your input; instead, that input should be properly escaped before being passed to the database.

How to escape input totally depends on what technology you are using to interface with the database.

> Use prepared statements and parameterized queries. These are SQL
>   statements that are sent to and parsed by the database server
>   separately from any parameters. This way it is impossible for an
>   attacker to inject malicious SQL.

[Lesson on SQL injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev) for your reference.[link2](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/706692/Preventing-SQL-Injection-Attacks)